# How to parse Date format server format To "MM/dd/YYYY"

Tags: android, date, datetime

I was found many solution but its not working for me.

I am trying to parse date to user selected date format.

I was getting date from server in this format **2016-06-30T00:00:00Z** UTC Timezone

Now I want to Parse it in User selected format **for e.g MM/dd/yyyy**

How Can i do that.? I was found many solution but its not working for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get date into a particular format, first you have to parse the date string into it's given format and there you will get `Date` object. Second, you can convert the date object into a desired format.

```
private String getFormattedDate(String strDate) {    
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    Date d= (Date)formatter.parse(strDate);

    SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    return fmtOut.format(date);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I was forget to parse in (Date). thank you so much

Comment: @VishalHalani welcome! If it has helped you then please up vote and accept the answer :)

Comment: @VishalHalani If this solved your problem, you should accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

This function help to convert any type of string date in any formate

```
public String getFormatedDate(String dateString, String format, String currentFormat) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(currentFormat, Locale.ENGLISH);
            try {
                Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
                String formated = new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(date);
                return formated;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");